# 3ds Max - Turn an uneven rectangle into a box

Tags: 3ds-max, games, modeling

I am a game programmer and I am trying to learn 3D Modelling by doing my own art for games. So I run into this problem:

I created this model using a Rectangle. Now, I want to give it more height. I am trying to achieve what this picture shows
[image]

I tried using extrude, but it does not do exactly what I need to do. This picture shows the results
[image]

I need the bottom of the box to be flat, so it will produce a box with a part of it missing.
Any ideas how to do this? I hope I made what I need to do clear. Note that I am a beginner in 3ds Max.

Thanks in Advance,

Jack

Comment: Hi Jack, Welcome to GDSE. Thanks for your question, it's pretty clear what you're trying to achieve. Most designers here are not really into 3D, but there are some around, so it might take some time to get an answer. Keep contributing and enjoy! See [help] for more info and help.

Comment: There is a proposal (future stackexchange site) dedicated to 3D, called [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation?referrer=4bIZIhmQJeWKQcyqcR7pKw2). Your question matches its scope 100%, have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if this is an Editable Poly, presumably you are on the halfway.

Use `Extrude` first, then switch to the front or left view, then select all the vertices which belong to the boottom of object and press `Make planar` button in the scroll `Edit Geometry`

Nevertheless, `Extrude` command won't give exactly what you want. Since your surface is not planar `Extrude` will not create a box. So the better sequence of commands would be:

1. Switch to an `Element` sublevel in modyfier and copy element by holding `Shift` and dragging it down simultaneously. Choose `Clone to Element`

[image: Copying element]

2. Choose new element (at bottom), switch to `Polygon` sublevel, click `Make planar` by and `Flip` normals (in edit polygons scroll)

[image: Making element planar and flipping polygons]

3. Switch to `Border` sublevel, select both porders and press Bridge

[image: Bridging]